# Delete one of two elements with same class

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have two HTML elements:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

Both have the same structure, class and attributes. How can I delete only one of them if I have two? (This is a bug)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select the buttons by class `.close`:

```
const [buttonOne, buttonTwo] = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
```

Then you can use:

- Remove it by using [Node.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

`document.querySelector('body').removeChild(buttonOne);`

- Remove it by using [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove):

`buttonOne.remove();`

- Or you can hide the element by using [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

`buttonOne.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: This one's the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DOM queries return arrays, so if more than one element matches you can access specific elements by index:

```js
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('close') // returns an array of matched elements
foo[1].remove(); // removes the second one
```

```html
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">First</span></button>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">Second</span></button>
```

(It would probably be better to correct whatever bug is inserting the duplicate button in the first place, of course, but I'll assume there are reasons that's impractical in your case.)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of javascript's document.getElementsByClassName and delete one of the list.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
buttons[0].parentNode.removeChild(buttons[0]);
```

```html
<div>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</div>
```